# My for loop is too complex - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm still writing a program in Excel VBA, and I've been stuck on a specific problem for hours. I'm trying to determine if someone is available on a specific day, but the information I'm given is for when they aren't available.

So I'm trying to write a series of for loops to compare all of this information and put it into Excel. I'm facing the issue, though, of the fact that it's quite complex:

```
 With ActiveSheet
'           Check the ID_Array and Date_Array to see if any names match
        For DateIndex = 0 To MinLimit
            For IDIndex = 0 To ID_Number
                'If (ID_Array(IDIndex, 0) = Date_Array(DateIndex, 0)) Then

'                   We're going to use our column not only as a match check, but as our way of ending the cycle
                For colCounter = 2 To 6
'                       If the date in the doc and the date in the array match, continue
                    If (.Cells(1, colCounter).Text = Date_Array(DateIndex, 1)) Then
                        For rowCounter = 2 To 11
'                               If the time slot in this row matches up with the time slot in the array, and the name also matches up, mark the name to be unused in this row
                            If (.Cells(rowCounter, 1).Text = Date_Array(DateIndex, 2)) Then
                                If (ID_Array(IDIndex, 0) = Date_Array(DateIndex, 0)) Then
                                    ID_Array(IDIndex, 3) = "1"
                                End If
                            End If

'                               If the name has not been flagged as 1, write it down in this row
                            If (ID_Array(IDIndex, 3) <> "1") Then
                                supahotstring = ", " + ID_Array(IDIndex, 1) + " " + ID_Array(IDIndex, 2)
                                .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Text + supahotstring
                            End If

'                               If the name HAS been flagged as 1, unflag it for the next row, since it might need to be written there
                            If (ID_Array(IDIndex, 3) = "1") Then
                                ID_Array(IDIndex, 3) = "0"
                            End If
'                               Now that all names can be checked for availability again, move on to the next row in this column
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
                'End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
```

Above is the series of for loops I'm using. for reference, I use SQL to draw in the data, so everything is organized by records.

Since the possible available dates are fixed, I use the values I have set up in my Excel doc as a comparison to the dates people have put in. Basically, if someone has marked a specific timeslot on a specific day, I want to flag the record with that name as "1" so that it doesn't get marked down in that row. Then, I see if the current name is marked as "1", apply the appropriate actions, unmark it as "1" so that it can be checked again later.

However, when I run the program, a variety of problems occur: sometimes, the program will freeze up and I'll be forced to end task (I save quite often these days). Other times, when I write, it will simply write the same names in the same order in every box.

I feel like this should be a relatively easy problem to fix, but at this point I need a second opinion. I need to talk it over with someone here who's willing to look at it, and perhaps even find a way to do this without using four for loops.

It's a fairly complex program, and if you need more code for reference then I'm willing to provide it. I've tried to comment this code enough that it's fairly easy to understand. I really appreciate any help you can give.

EDIT: I cannot provide an image of expected output, but I can describe it. Imagine John Doe is going to be available on the first day, after 9:00AM. The program simply writes his name, along with every else's names, eleven time in each box.

Comment: If you could edit the post and an image with input data and expected output, it would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm currently working on a possible fix, but will update in a few minutes if it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the question is still vague. There are some arrays of unknown structure and you compare it to some unknown range headers. Also if you use SQL to import data, would it be an option to change the way it's imported? Many SQL engines can handle concatenation.